# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() using panda python

Tags: python, pandas

Here I have data to import from a CSV file.I wrote an equation inside the class and to solve the equation data will import from the CSV file. 
When I run my code I got an error like "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str" using panda python.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
I upload my code and CSV file here.

```
def time_convert(x):
    h,m,s = map(int,x.split(':'))
    return (h*60+m)

def ph_convert(time,we,h,a,w):
    while time <= 30:
        level = 1.1
        level = float(level)
        if w == 1:
            ph= ((((6*we)+(1*h))/level -(4*a)))/time
        else:
            ph= ((6+((1*we)+(3*h))/level -(6 *a)))/time  
        break
    while time <=60:
        level = 1.25
        level = float(level)
        if w == 1:
            ph= ((((6*we)+(1*h))/level -(4*a)))/time
        else:
            ph= ((6+((1*we)+(3*h))/level -(6 *a)))/time  
        break
    print(ph)

data = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
data['time'] = data['time'].apply(time_convert)
we = data['we'].astype(float)
h = data['h'].astype(float)
a = data['a'].astype(float)
w = data['w'].astype(float)
time = data['time'].astype(float)
print(ph_convert(time,we,h,a,w))
```

Subset of my CSV file:

```
we      h   a   w   time
48.1    150 53  1   6:15:00
48.1    150 53  1   9:00:00
48.1    150 53  1   9:25:00
48.1    150 53  1   9:30:00
48.1    150 53  1   11:00:00
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-922-9fe360350b03> in <module>()
----> 1 print(ph_convert(time,we,h,a,w))

<ipython-input-904-73455dabb050> in ph_convert(time, we, h, a, w)
      3    
----> 5         while time <= 30:
      6             level = 1.1
      7             level = float(level)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1571         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1572                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1573                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1574 
   1575     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: What's time_convert function doing?

Comment: @MohitMotwani it convert my time into minutes. code is :-def time_convert(x):
    h,m,s = map(int,x.split(':'))
    return (h*60+m)

Comment: The `time`(and other variables) is actually a series.  Your function expects a single value of time(int, float) not a series. Hence you're getting this error.

Comment: @MohitMotwani can you give me any suggestions to solve this error? I didn't have any ideas to solve this.

Comment: Do you want a new column where each row has it's own ph_convert value?

Comment: @MohitMotwani yes I need a new column .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `while` to `if` and `elif` and add `else` if `time > 60`:

```
def ph_convert(time,we,h,a,w):
    if time <= 30:
        level = 1.1
        if w == 1:
            ph= ((((6*we)+(1*h))/level -(4*a)))/time
        else:
            ph= ((6+((1*we)+(3*h))/level -(6 *a)))/time  
    elif time <=60:
        level = 1.25
        if w == 1:
            ph= ((((6*we)+(1*h))/level -(4*a)))/time
        else:
            ph= ((6+((1*we)+(3*h))/level -(6 *a)))/time  
    else:
        ph = np.nan

    return ph
```

And assign back values to columns:

```
data['time'] = data['time'].apply(time_convert).astype(float)
data['we'] = data['we'].astype(float)
data['h'] = data['h'].astype(float)
data['a'] = data['a'].astype(float)
data['w'] = data['w'].astype(float)
```

Last call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for processes per rows:

```
print(data.apply(lambda x: ph_convert(x.time,x.we,x.h,x.a,x.w), axis=1))
```

Comment: @awa - with sample data it return NaN, because not defined what happen if `time > 60`.

Comment: @awa - Question is what need return if `time > 60` ?

Comment: @awa - because if check `print (time)` it return times > 60

Comment: @awa - not sure, but you need return from `def time_convert(x):` - > `return (h*60+m)` ? Not `return m` ? Or something else?

Comment: @jerzrael Can I write that if time>60 then ph =2500 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184601/discussion-between-awa-and-jezrael).

Comment: @awa - yes, very easy - ph = np.select([m1, m3], [ph1, ph2], default=2500) and in second solution `else:
        ph = 2500`

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function like this:

```
def ph_convert(x):
    print(x.time)
    print(type(x.time))
    ph = 2500
    if x.time <= 30:
        level = float(1.1)
        if x.w == 1:
            ph= ((((6*x.we)+(1*x.h))/level -(4*x.a)))/x.time
        else:
            ph= ((6+((1*x.we)+(3*x.h))/level -(6 *x.a)))/x.time  
    elif x.time <=60:
        level = 1.25
        if x.w == 1:
            ph= ((((6*x.we)+(1*x.h))/level -(4*x.a)))/x.time
        else:
            ph= ((6+((1*x.we)+(3*x.h))/level -(6 *x.a)))/x.time
    return ph
```

Then use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
data['ph'] = data.apply(ph_convert, axis =1)
```